# Is there a way to truncate active_admin's displayed content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I use Active_admin in my Rails app, which I use to write long articles.

The only problem I have is when I list all the articles, I get to see all of them but also the article's full content. Is there a way to truncate what the index displays to win some space? I haven't seen anything close to this in all the documentation I could find about active_admin. Of course, I tried something like `truncate(:content), :length => 200)` but it didn't work

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am using this:

```
column "Content", sortable: :content do |post|
  post.content.truncate(200, separator: /\s/)
end
```